# Mockito - how to mock/verify a method call which accepts a new object?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a method (method1) that I'd like to test, which based on parameters provided creates an object and calls another method (method2). So I'm mocking method2, which accepts an object (sampleObj).

```java
public void method1(booleanParam) {
    if(booleanParam){
        List<SampleObj> fooList = new ArrayList<SampleObj>;
        fooList.add(new SampleObj("another param"));
        anotherService.method2(fooList);
    }
    //some other smart logic here
}
```

And here's my test with same obfuscated names (sorry if I missed any typo):

```java
public void testMethod1() {
    AnotherService mockedAnotherService = PowerMockito.mock(AnotherService.class);
    ServicesFactory.getInstance().setMock(AnotherService.class, mockedAnotherService);

    List<SampleObj> fooList = new ArrayList<SampleObj>;
    fooList.add(new SampleObj("another param"));

    // assert and verify
    service.method1(true);
    Mockito.verify(mockedAnotherService, times(1)).method2(fooList);
}
```

The problem is, when I try to mock the anotherService, I need to pass an object to method2, so I have to create a new one. But since it's a new object, it's not the same object, which will be passed from inside the method1, hence the test fails with the exception:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
anotherService.method2(
    [com.smart.company.SampleObj@19c59e46]
);
-> at <test filename and line # here>
Actual invocation has different arguments:
anotherService.method2(
    [com.smart.company.SampleObj@7d1a12e1]
);
-> at <service filename and line # here>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Implement `equals` and `hashCode` on `SampleObj`. Because you didn't wrap `fooList` in a matcher, Mockito checks with `List.equals`, which checks `equals` for corresponding objects in each List. The default behavior of Object.equals is that `a.equals(b)` iff `a == b`--that is, objects are equal iff they refer to the same instance--but you're welcome to override that if every SampleObj("foobar") equals every other SampleObj("foobar").
2. Use a Hamcrest Matcher you write.

   ```
   private static Matcher<List<SampleObj>> isAListWithObjs(String... strings) {
     return new AbstractMatcher<List<SampleObj>>() {
       @Override public boolean matches(Object object) {
         // return true if object is a list of SampleObj corresponding to strings
       }
     };
   }

   // in your test
   verify(mockedAnotherService).method2(argThat(isAnObjListWith("another param")));
   ```

   Note that you could also just make a Matcher of a single SampleObj, and then use a Hamcrest wrapper like `hasItem`. [See more matchers here.](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html)
3. Use a Captor to check `equals` your own way:

   ```
   public class YourTest {
     // Populated with MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this).
     // You can also use ArgumentCaptor.forClass(...), but with generics trouble.
     @Captor ArgumentCaptor<List<SampleObj>> sampleObjListCaptor;

     @Test public void testMethod1() {
       // ...
       verify(mockedAnotherService).method2(sampleObjListCaptor.capture());
       List<SampleObj> sampleObjList = sampleObjListCaptor.getValue();

       assertEquals(1, sampleObjList.size());
       assertEquals("another param", sampleObjList.get(0).getTitle());
     }
   ```