# Mokito: How to Verify that a parameter is an Object with a specific parameter?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I have an EventBus that is posted as below

```
EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
bus.post(new MyEvent("mystring", json));
```

I wanted to perform a unit test to ensure this bus has called a post function, with the MyEvent Object.

```
EventBus bus = mock(EventBus.class);
verify(bus).post(isA(MyEvent.class));
```

The above code works well. However, I also wanted to ensure "mystring" is passed to the MyEvent object during the instantiation. How could I achieve that?

Comment: if(bus.get("mystring") != null) check this condition

Comment: Generally you don't want to verify how objects are constructed, since that is very implementation specific and really not important. The important thing is how the MyEvent will be used. Does it provide a way of accessing mystring?

Comment: May I mark as a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30792006/1426891)? Though yours isn't necessarily a new object, you have the same choices—`equals`/`hashCode`, a custom Matcher, or a Captor solution as Vova describes below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that you pass some concrete object to method you can use Mockito `@Captor`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public TestClass{

@Mock
private EventBus bus;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<MyEvent> myEventCaptor;

@Test
public void testSaveAccount() {
    methodToTest();

    verify(bus).post(myEventCaptor.capture());
    MyEvent myEvent = myEventCaptor.getValue(); // last value that was captured
    assertThat(myEvent.getString, is("mystring"));
}
```