# How can I verify that a method is called with a parameter that contains a certain value, without verifying the whole parameter?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a method that returns no results. The last step of the method is something like:

```
insertIntoDb(someObjectContainingAListField);
```

I could do

```
verify(xx).insertIntoDb(eq(someObjectContainingAListField));
```

But that would verify the entire object contents; I only need to verify the list.

I really only want to verify that the List it contains is correct.

Is there any way to do so in Mockito?

Answer (score 2):

You have two main choices: Use an ArgumentCaptor, or write an ArgumentMatcher.

### ArgumentCaptor

[ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.16/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) lets you get a reference to the object as part of your verification, so then you can make specific assertions about it. You can create them manually with ArgumentCaptor.forClass, or use the @Captor annotation with MockitoAnnotations or the Mockito Runner or Rule.

```
@Captor ArgumentCaptor<ListFieldContainer> listFieldContainerCaptor;

@Test public void yourTest() {
  yourClass.doSomething();
  verify(mockService).insertIntoDb(listFieldContainerCaptor.capture());
  ListFieldContainer listFieldContainer = listFieldContainerCaptor.getValue();
  assertEquals(3, listFieldContainer.getListField().size());
}
```

## ArgumentMatcher (or Matcher)

Using a Mockito [ArgumentMatcher](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.16/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) or a [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/) [Matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html), you can create an object that represents the predicate you're looking for.

```
@Test public void yourTest() {
  yourClass.doSomething();
  verify(mockService).insertIntoDb(argThat(
      new ArgumentMatcher<ListFieldContainer>() {
        @Override public boolean matches(ListFieldContainer container) {
          return (container.size() == 3);
        }
      });
}
```

Note that previous versions of Mockito relied directly on Hamcrest, such that [Matchers.argThat](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher)) took a Hamcrest matcher; newer versions of Mockito use [ArgumentMatchers.argThat](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.16/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat(org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher)) to take a Hamcrest-like ArgumentMatcher interface and [MockitoHamcrest.argThat](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.16/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html) to adapt a proper Hamcrest matcher.

See also: [Mockito - how to mock/verify a method call which accepts a new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30792006/1426891)