# Mockito when checking for specific object property value

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following in a working test:

```
when(client.callApi(anyString(), isA(Office.class))).thenReturn(responseOne);
```

Note that client is a Mock of class Client.

I want to change "isA(Office.class)" to tell it to match where the "id" property of an Office instance is "123L". How can I specify that I want a specific argument value in the method of a mocked object?

Edit: Not a duplicate because I'm trying to use it on a "when" and the linked question (and other resources I've found) are using ArgumentCaptor and ArgumentMatcher on "verify" and "assert". I'm thinking I can't actually do what I'm trying and will try out another way. Of course, I'm willing to be shown otherwise.

Comment: Marking as a dupe of this one: ["How can I verify that a method is called with a parameter that contains a certain value, without verifying the whole parameter?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40617085/1426891). In short, use an ArgumentMatcher or Hamcrest Matcher to check.

Answer (score 28):

Reopening as requested, but the solution (use an ArgumentMatcher) is identical to [the one in the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617085/1426891). Naturally, you can't use an `ArgumentCaptor` when stubbing, but everything else is the same.

```
class OfficeWithId implements ArgumentMatcher<Office> {
  long id;

  OfficeWithId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override public boolean matches(Office office) {
    return office.id == id;
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return "[Office with id " + id + "]";
  }
}

when(client.callApi(anyString(), argThat(new IsOfficeWithId(123L)))
    .thenReturn(responseOne);
```

Because ArgumentMatcher has a single method, you can even make it a lambda in Java 8:

```
when(client.callApi(anyString(), argThat(office -> office.id == 123L))
    .thenReturn(responseOne);
```

If you're already using Hamcrest, you can adapt a Hamcrest matcher using `MockitoHamcrest.argThat`, or use the built-in [`hasProperty`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasProperty(java.lang.String,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)):

```java
when(client.callApi(
  anyString(),
  MockitoHamcrest.argThat(
    hasProperty("id", equalTo(123L)))))
  .thenReturn(responseOne);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Something in the project doesn't seem to be set up right and doesn't like argThat. I'll troubleshoot that later.

Comment: @eflat Check your versions. `argThat` changed between 1.x and 2.x; in 1.x Mockito's `ArgumentMatcher` extended Hamcrest's `Matcher` and `Matchers.argThat` supported both, but they diverged for better versioning in 2.x and the Hamcrest `argThat` became `MockitoHamcrest.argThat`. If you've got both versions on your classpath, crazy things can happen.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going with "eq". This was ok in this case because the objects are pretty simple. First I created an object that is the same as what I expect to get back.

```
Office officeExpected = new Office();
officeExpected.setId(22L);
```

Then my 'when' statement becomes:

```
when(client.callApi(anyString(), eq(officeExpected))).thenReturn(responseOne);
```

This allows me to have better checking than "isA(Office.class)".

Answer (score 1):

adding an answer for anyone with a more complex object.

answer from OP uses [eq](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq-T-) which works for simple objects.

However, I had a more complex object with many more fields. Its quite painful to create Mock object and fill in all the fields

```
public class CreateTenantRequest {
  @NotBlank private String id;
  @NotBlank private String a;
  @NotBlank private String b;
  ...
  ...
  
}
```

I was able to use [refEq](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#refEq-T-java.lang.String...-) to achieve the same thing without setting a value of each field.

```
Office officeExpected = new Office();
officeExpected.setId(22L);

verify(demoMock, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).foobarMethod(refEq(officeExpected, "a", "b"));
```